# Play custom sound(texturepack) that doesn't exist in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Well, I am working on a custom texture pack for my very big map. And I found that after I replaced all the sound(like sound of taking damage, open door etc.) to custom sound for the map, it is still not enough. I need to have 3 more audio to add into the texture pack.

So my question is... Can I put a custom sound that doesn't exists in Minecraft into the texture pack and play the sound in game with the texture pack by /playsound. ? Or there is some way else to add more custom sound?

Comment: Some of you may asks: Why don't you try it yourself?

Actually I use data at the moment, and the custom sound are in the format .mp3 so I will  need to convert them into .ogg . This waste a lot of data, so I need to make sure it works, then I can convert them without wasting my data, If they doesn't work, I will need to find another way...

Comment: [Does this help?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUBp2UxUWrY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using resource packs, you can add your own sounds to the game. However, they must be in .ogg format.

Just drop your sound in the /sounds/ directory of your resource pack and move it to anywhere.

In game, the code will be the directory of it after /sounds/ with slashes replaced with periods.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the playSound command if you change a specific sound to one of the ones you need to add. For example, you may not need the `ambient.cave` sound, so you could replace that sound with one of the new ones you wish to add and then use `/playsound ambient.cave` to play it.

[Here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/mapping-and-modding-tutorials/1571574-all-minecraft-playsound-file-names) is a link to all of the possible sounds that you can use playsound to play.

Just pick any one you don't need, replace it, and then play it through playsound!

Comment: That doesn't answer my question :/ What I mean is I already replaced all my sound but I need to have 3 more sound to add, means that there is no more sound to replace